# Middleman not running Regex function locally

Tags: php, middleman

I have this simple  php function

```
<?php
$ELASTIC_SEARCH_SPECIAL_KEYWORDS = "/[\\+\\-\\=\\&\\|\\!\\(\\)\\{\\}\\[\\]\\^\\\"\\~\\*\\<\\>\\?\\:\\\\\\/]/";

function escapeESReservedChars($text) {
  global $ELASTIC_SEARCH_SPECIAL_KEYWORDS;
  $result = preg_replace_callback ($ELASTIC_SEARCH_SPECIAL_KEYWORDS,
    function ($matches) {
      return "\\" . $matches[0];
    }, $text);
  return $result;
}
```

Here `$text` is any text message where if there is any special chars,it will replace that with `\\`

It run only when i make build & upload to server. If i run this file on `localhost` it neither run not throw any error. There is no problem with this function. I think `middleman` is doing something behind the screen.

Comment: How do you call `escapeESReservedChars`? Seems like `$ELASTIC_SEARCH_SPECIAL_KEYWORDS` would be out of scope...

Comment: Okay so what is `$text`? Also I'd recommend single quotes for your regex string to make it more readable.

Comment: `$text` is just any text

Comment: Okay so why run a regex on "any text"?

Comment: Here `$text` is any text message where if there is any special chars,it will replace that with \\. e.g `(hello)` - > `\(hello\)`

Comment: I think I gotta come back to this tomorrow... maybe try regex101.com before hand..